# Unity error CS0119 moving an object

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I just started learning programming in unity - moved from Eclipse, Android Studio. So , I followed some tutorial in youtube but I get an error like this :

```
Assets/Scripts/Move.cs(9,17): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `method group', where a `variable', `value' or `type' was expected
```

My very simple code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {
void FixedUpdate(){
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>.velocity = movement;
   }
 }
```

Usually the problem is in the constructor with the word new as I saw online, but I had it all the time, what's different from my tutorial online here : https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=206&v=rVSLczG1M1E is that the line `rigidbody.velocity=movement` gave me errors so I looked up online and changed it but it still give me this error. thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is incorrect

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>.velocity = movement;
```

It should read

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = movement;
```

with the parenthesis.